# Utilizing OpenAPI Specifications in JSON Format as a Contract for Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, spring-cloud-contract

I have several questions about using OpenAPI specs as a contract for Spring Cloud Contract. Specifically:

1.Can I use spring-cloud-contract-oa3 with OpenAPI specs in JSON format?

2.If so, can you provide an example of how to use it?

3.Do I need to replicate the entire OpenAPI file in the contracts directory, or can I simply provide the path to my OpenAPI specs file?

I'm feeling confused about this and would appreciate any insights from someone who has experience working with this. Thank you!

I attempted to use OpenAPI specifications in YAML format as contracts by studying relevant examples and converting them to OpenAPI specifications in JSON format, but was unable to achieve success. I searched online for examples, but couldn't find any that were useful. Additionally, I tried to run an example available at https://github.com/springframeworkguru/sccoa3-fraud-example, but it threw some errors and did not work as expected.